# How to switch between audio outputs when both headphones and speakers are connected?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

I have the M5A97 motherboard, with the audio ports displayed on this picture:

[image]

As you can see on the part labelled "Audio", there are 6 jacks.

By default, the pink one is configured to be the microphone input, and the green one to be the speakers output. (I think some others are also outputs but I think that's irrelevant.)

I'd like to permanently plug in my headset *and* my speakers, and then alternate the output between each of them in software (preferably some easily accessible sound options).

Note that I said **alternate** - meaning only a single output is active at the time. I don't want my speakers blasting when I select the headset as the output, vice-versa.

The microphone is on the headset, and will also be plugged in at all times, but of course should as well be toggled in software.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Sound Switcher Indicator or Pulse Audio Volume Control....

**Sound Switcher Indicator**

*"Sound input/output selector indicator for Ubuntu/Unity"* -- github.com/yktoo/indicator-sound-switcher

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yktooo/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound-switcher
```

**Pulse Audio Volume Control**

*"PulseAudio Volume Control (pavucontrol) is a simple GTK based volume control tool ("mixer") for the PulseAudio sound server. In contrast to classic mixer tools this one allows you to control both the volume of hardware devices and of each playback stream separately."* -- freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/pavucontrol/

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```